# Managed Property for Version History & Comments

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, managed-property, modern-experience

I'm currently working with a spfx web part that utilized managed properties to pull information about documents. I would like to be able to pull the most recent version and the comment associated with that version being published. However, all the out of box managed properties ive tried have only pulled the version number, and not the comment.

I would like to know if it is possible to pull at least the most recent version number and comment. And optimally, the complete version history and comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of box managed property for most recent version and comment associated with the version.

So, you could create the managed property and map with the crawled property “ows__CheckinComment”.

There is no crawled property for the most recent version. We only can get the version number. It is by design.

After all, in SharePoint online, the crawl runs backend and automatically. You should wait for a period of time.

Comment: Perfect! this works well for what i need! Out of curiousity though, is there any property that pulls a total list of the version history? Maybe something that contains an array of all the check in comments?

Comment: I am afraid there is no managed property that pulls list of the version history.